# How do I update each row individually?

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql, forms

So I've been trying for days to figure out how I can update each row separately and i can't figure it out. this is the first time I've used php so sorry for the ugly code.

I can seem to pull the information from each row but the update wont work, however it sends all the data from all the rows in the address bar

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>EDIT Patient data</title>
</head>
<body> 
    <br>
    <a href="Patients.php">Edit Patients</a><br>
    <a href="PatientRequest.php">Patient Request</a><br>
    <a href="PatientConfirmed.php">Booked Patients</a>
    <?php
        include 'connect.php';
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM patients;";
        $result = mysql_query($sql);
        $num_of_row = mysql_num_rows($result);

        if (isset($_GET['submit'])) {
            $id = $_GET['did'];
            $fname = $_GET['dfname'];
            $lname = $_GET['dlname'];
            $email = $_GET['demail'];
            $phone = $_GET['dphone'];
            $address = $_GET['daddress'];
            $query = mysql_query("update patients set fName='$fname', lName='$lname', email='email', phone='$phone', address='$address' where patientID ='$id'");
        }

        echo "<table border=1>";
        echo " <tr> <td> Patient ID </td>  ";
        echo "<td> First name </td>";
        echo "<td> last name </td>";
        echo "<td> email </td>";
        echo "<td> phone number</td>";
        echo "<td> address </td>";
        echo "<td> date of birth </td> ";
        echo "<td> update </td></tr>";

        while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
        {
            echo  "<tr> <form class='form' method='get'>";
            echo  "<td> <input type='text' name='did' value='".$row['patientID']."' readonly /></td>";
            echo  "<td> <input type='text' name='dfname' value ='".$row['fName']."' /></td>";
            echo  "<td> <input type='text' name='dlname' value = '".$row['lName']."' /></td>";
            echo  "<td> <input type='text' name='demail' value = '".$row['email']."' /></td>";
            echo  "<td> <input type='text' name='dphone' value ='".$row['phone']."' /></td>";
            echo  "<td> <input type='text' name='daddress' value ='".$row['address']."' /></td>";
            echo  "<td> <input type='text' name='ddob'  value ='".$row['dob']."' readonly /></td>"; 
            echo  "<td>  <input class='submit' type='submit' name='submit' value='update' /> </td> </tr>";
        }    

    ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Don't use `mysql_*` but use `mysqli_*` or PDO because `mysql_*` has been deprecated and in PHP 7 it will be deleted.

Comment: To start, use $_POST instead of $_GET for these types of form submissions. Replace `$_GET` with `$_POST` and change `method='get'` to `method='post'`

Comment: Okay, so I've changed that but it's still not updating, like I said I'm a bit of a noob at this so I'm sorry if it's something simple

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to update an individual row, you'll have to put a `<form>` around your while-loop, like this:

```
echo "<form action='' method='GET'>";
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
      echo  "<tr> <form class='form' method='get'>";
      echo  "<td> <input type='text' name='did' value='".$row['patientID']."' readonly /></td>";
      echo  "<td> <input type='text' name='dfname' value ='".$row['fName']."' /></td>";
      echo  "<td> <input type='text' name='dlname' value = '".$row['lName']."' /></td>";
      echo  "<td> <input type='text' name='demail' value = '".$row['email']."' /></td>";
      echo  "<td> <input type='text' name='dphone' value = '".$row['phone']."' /></td>";
      echo  "<td> <input type='text' name='daddress' value ='".$row['address']."' /></td>";
      echo  "<td> <input type='text' name='ddob'  value ='".$row['dob']."' readonly /></td>"; 
      echo  "<td>  <input class='submit' type='submit' name='submit' value='update' /> </td> </tr>";
}
echo "</form>";
```

The form will allow input fields to be submit according to the form's method (GET and POST).

Answer (score 1):

Does your user have update permissions?

If not you need to use `GRANT UPDATE ON *.* TO 'User'@'Host';`

But you should use MySQLi as MySQL is deprecated. You should also look into Parameterized Queries and MySQL injection, It's worth knowing about!

Comment: In a MySQL shell or on phpmyadmin? Which one are you using?